# How to correctly send JSON to google function?

Tags: jquery, web, google-cloud-platform

Here is the simple server code in python

```
def post_petition(request):
    return pprint.pformat(request.get_json())
```

When I test the function using the tester through google I get the correct json. However when I test it with something like this

```
$.post("https://us-central1-radiant-shard-XXXXX.cloudfunctions.net/post_petition", {"name":"hello"}, function(data){
alert(data);
});
```

I always get None as the return. How do I get the return to correctly return the JSON input?

Comment: Hello ! your code is correct, but you sure you are not receiving an error because of CORS, authentication or other issues ?

Comment: You are not sending json, you are sending a form encoded request which is $.ajax default. You need to set contentType and stringify the object to send it as json

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) HTTP functions require [authentication by default](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) it means that only project owners and editors can create, update or delete functions.
But you can [configure IAM on HTTP functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access) to specify whether a function allows unauthenticated invocation.
Adding users:

```
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding FUNCTION_NAME \
  --member=MEMBER_TYPE \
  --role=ROLE
```

You can use Cloud Console settings or include the `--allow-unauthenticated`  flag with the `gcloud deploy` command to allow [unauthenticated invocation of an HTTP function.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation)

Something like :

```
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME \
  --trigger-http \
--allow-unauthenticated \
...
```

Additionally, you can found further information regarding [HTTP Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) where you can find some examples that may help you.